# Is there any way to get the amount of time "people typically spend" at a place with Google Places API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I've noticed Google has had this feature for about a year now but I don't see it on Google Places API. If you look up a library or a gym near you, Google will show how long people typically spend at the place (like a gym nearby me, "People typically spend 45 min to 1 hr here.") Is there any way to get this information on Google Places API or is it not available yet?

Comment: want to use for geo fence or any location that user going? @SaltySea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right this information is not available via Places API yet. I can see that people have already filed a feature request for this in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830308

I would suggest staring the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications. Hopefully one day Google will implement this feature in the API.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, Google Places API currently does not have any functionality to provide that information. You may consider filling a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) through Google Code. Alternatively, I'd advise to simply look up the place (in your app, that is) and parse the typical visit duration manually. There are many drawbacks to this solution depending on the method you're gonna use (such as the layout of the page may change and your app will stop working, requiring an immediate update), but it's an option.